# change date to now if date is not set

Tags: php, jquery, get

i want to change `http://localhost/devReservation/list.php?item-date=` to `item-date=NOW` or `item-date=3/25/2015` if item-date is not set.

Code is:

```
$itemdate=isset($_GET['item-date']) ? $_GET['item-date']: 'item-date=date("Y-m-d")';
```

Comment: Change it _where_? You need to provide a lot more context.

Answer (score 0):

Make it as

```
$itemdate = ( isset( $_GET['item-date'] ) && !empty( $_GET['item-date'] ) ) ? $_GET['item-date'] : date("Y-m-d") ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
$itemdate= (isset($_GET['item-date']) && $_GET['item-date'] != '') ? $_GET['item-date'] : date("Y-m-d");
```

Or like this

```
  <?php  $itemdate=isset($_GET['item-date']) {
   $itemdate =  $_GET['item-date'];
  } else{
    $itemdate = date("Y-m-d");
  }  ?>
```